# Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов

Tags: поддержка, faq, вопросы, дух-сообщества, удаление-вопросов

Как мне кажется, не все участники сообщества знают, что именно происходит с заброшенными вопросами. “В прошлой жизни” мы использовали специальные фильтры и два раза в год вручную просматривали форум на наличие вопросов, которые следовало бы удалить.

[image: Сортировки на ХэшКоде]

В сообществе Stack Overflow на русском действуют другие правила удаления заброшенных вопросов. Возможно, вы уже видели пользователя [Дух сообщества ♦](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/). Он удаляет вопросы самостоятельно, без вмешательства кого-либо, в следующих ситуациях:

**Если вопросу более `30` дней и выполняются все следующие условия:**

- он имеет рейтинг -1 и менее;
- он не имеет ответов;
- он не заблокирован;

**или если:**

- он был закрыт и перенесен на другой сайт Сети;

то он будет удален.

**Если вопросу более `365` дней и выполняются все следующие условия:**

- он имеет рейтинг 0 **или** рейтинг 1 **и** учетная запись автора удалена;
- он не имеет ответов;
- он не заблокирован;
- он имеет количество просмотров <= возраст вопроса в днях * 1.5;
- он имеет один или менее комментариев;

то он будет удален.

Такие проверки запускаются автоматически каждую неделю на всех сайтах Сети.

**Если вопрос был закрыт более `9` дней назад и выполняются все следующие условия:**

- он был закрыт с причиной отличной от “дубликат”;
- он имеет рейтинг 0 или менее;
- он не заблокирован;
- он не имеет ответов с рейтингом более нуля;
- он не имеет принятых ответов;
- он не имеет голосов за повторное открытие в ожидании;
- он не редактировался в течение последних `9` дней;

то он также будет удален.

Эти проверки выполняются каждый день на всех сайтах Сети.

В дополнение, вы можете прочитать публикацию ["How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) на Meta Stack Exchange.

---

Этот пост является переводом ответа [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood). Ссылка на оригинал: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/274323

Comment: @NickVolynkin Скорее всего, то, о чем вы говорите - это другой случай. [Пожалуйста, посмотрите, что данный пользователь написал о себе в своей учётной записи](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile).

Comment: В описании мета-бота пропущено тире: "Я выдуманный персонаж, процесс-демон" =)

Comment: @SergeySnegirev Поправил, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это не тире (—), это минус (-), но для сайта программистов это ОК.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev Готово.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо! :)

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, тире в данном контексте [не обязательно](http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/25821). И для меня оно выглядит несколько чужродно в той фразе.

Comment: Тут есть двусмысленность: _он имеет рейтинг 0 **или** рейтинг 1 **и** учетная запись автора удалена_ — это (_он имеет рейтинг 0 **или** рейтинг 1) **и** учетная запись автора удалена_ или _он имеет рейтинг 0 **или** (рейтинг 1 **и** учетная запись автора удалена_)? В оригинале двусмысленности нет, правильный второй вариант. Но как можно переформулировать, не соображу.