# Обновить ссылки в профиле Духа сообщества

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, дух-сообщества

В профиле [Духа сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) есть такая строка:

- [удаляю "заброшенные" вопросы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Ссылка ведет на вопрос на Meta.SE, где есть ответ Jeff Atwood. Этот ответ переведен на нашей Мете: [Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/181472).

Предлагаю поменять старую ссылку на новую:

```
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/
```

Заодно можно кавычки заменить на ёлочки. Получится как-то так:

```
* [удаляю «заброшенные» вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/) 
<!-- Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов. -->
```

Comment: @Nicolas оперативно )