# Закрытие вопросов годовалой давности

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

В последнее время часто встречаются предложения с закрытием старых вопросов. Действительно содержание их зачастую представляет вопросы-опросники, но с большим количеством ответом и с принятым ответом.

Так вот вопрос - стоит ли закрывать вопросы с принятым ответом, ведь как я понимаю, *"КПД" сайта, которое сейчас равно 79%, при их закрытии снижается*, верно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "КПД" сайта, которое сейчас равно 79%, при их закрытии снижается, верно?

Нет, ничуть не снижается. Поскольку вопросы заплюсованы, то [garbage collector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) их [не собирает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/181472).

Да и вообще, не в КПД счастье, а в хороших вопросах и ответах. Аттестация сайта - как аттестация человека. Приятно иметь корочку, но полезнее иметь знания. Я и сам очень хочу скорой аттестации сайта, но скорей для того, чтобы уделать португальцев.

Вопрос можно только вручную удалить, но это стоит делать только с совсем субъективными и малополезными вопросами. Например, удаленный вчера [вопрос о снах на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/264529/181472).

Если вопрос не по теме, но даны какие-то хорошие объективные ответы - ладно, пускай будут. Но такой вопрос стоит закрыть, чтобы не привлекать новые ответы. Как правило, эти новые ответы поступают от новичков на сайте и не содержат объективной информации. Ещё лучше, на мой взгляд, вешать на вопрос history lock, явно обозначающий, что вопрос был популярен, мы его оставили, но больше об этом не стоит спорить.

Для удовлетворения потребности в общении есть чат (в последние дни он прямо-таки кипит). А если опытный участник очень хочет дать субъективный ответ на волнующий его вопрос, он всегда найдёт [лазейку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Если вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта, смело выставляйте голос за закрытие. Работаем не на КПД, а на то, чтобы был хороший сайт без мусора.

Также ради повышения КПД не надо голосовать за плохие ответы (чтобы вопрос перешёл в категорию отвеченных) или закрывать нормальные вопросы, на которые ответа нет. КПД — это не самоцель.