# Перевод страницы roomba

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Не переведена страница [roomba](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: Она совсем недавно появилась.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не выдержал, перевёл :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не мог смотреть на неё, решил сам перевести (:

## Дух сообщества удалил мой вопрос! Что случилось?

[Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) автоматически удаляет заброшенные / мертвые вопросы в следующих случаях:

**Если вопросу более `30` дней, и ...**

- имеет рейтинг −1 или менее
- не имеет ответов
- не защищён

**...или...**

- Был закрыт или перемещён на другой сайт

...он будет автоматически удален. Такие вопросы называются "мёртвыми" (`RemoveDeadQuestions` или `RemoveMigrationStubs` в случае переноса).

**Если вопрос задан более `365` дней назад и ...**

- имеет рейтинг 0, **или** 1 в случае удаления автором
- не имеет ответов
- не защищён
- имеет количество просмотров <= возраста вопроса помноженного на 1.5
- имеет 0 или 1 комментарий

... он будет автоматически удалён. Такие вопросы называются "заброшенными"(`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).

Эти проверки выполняются каждую неделю на всех сайтах.

**Если вопрос закрыт более `9` дней назад, и ...**

- не закрыт как дубликат
- имеет рейтинг 0 или менее
- не защищён
- не имеет ответов с рейтингом > 0
- не имеет подтверждённого ответа
- не имеет голосов за открытие
- не редактировался последние `9` дней

.. он будет автоматически удалён. Это "закрытые заброшенные" вопросы (`RemoveAbandonedClosed`).

Эти проверки происходят каждый день по всем сайтам.

Смотрите также этот вопрос на Мете: `«https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392»` «[Автоматическое удаление заброшенных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392)»

Comment: Тут надо свериться с текущим текстом справки. Официальный пост у нас переведен уже, кстати.