# Необходимость причесывания закрытых сообщений

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Хочется поинтересоваться мнением Сообщества по поводу необходимости облагораживания закрытых вопросов и ответом к ним.

Например, есть вопрос, написанный с ашипками, очепятками, не содержащий `normal'no`

```
оформленного 
            кода
```

и т.д. При этом такой вопрос закрыт по одной из причин (я думаю, причина не так важна).

Есть ли смысл в приведении такого вопроса и, возможно, ответов к нему, если они уже были на момент закрытия, к более цивилизованному виду? Или, ну его нафиг, закрыт (о необходимости переоткрытия вопроса речи не идет) - даже трогать не стоит.

Comment: Думаю, это вопрос приоритетов. Вообще можно, но если есть свежий и незакрытый вопрос, то больше пользы будет от правки такого вопроса. Или если вопрос закрыт, но автор подаёт признаки жизни и дополняет его. Тогда форматирование и правка ошибок будут полезны, потому что спасут от кровотечения глаза многих читателей. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin почему не в качестве ответа опубликовали?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зависит от причины закрытия, количества голосов и количества ответов в вопросе. Дух сообщества время от времени [удаляет заброшенные вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/). Как видно, [далеко не все закрытые вопросы удаляются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3ayes). Задача сообщества – поддерживать актуальность и качество базы знаний.

Если видно, что закрытый вопрос не удовлетворяет условиям автоматического удаления, с большой вероятностью, приведение его в порядок, положительно отразится на будущем сообщества, так как попавшие в вопрос, например, из поисковика коллеги, не просто быстрее и лучше разберутся в теме, но и увидят то, как мы относимся к нашей базе знаний и, возможно, переймут стиль общения.