# Целесообразность автоматического удаления неотвеченных вопросов с рейтингом -1 и менее без уведомлений авторов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-вопросов

### Правила

- [**Ссылка 1**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/199934)

> В сообществе Stack Overflow на русском действуют другие правила удаления заброшенных вопросов. Возможно, вы уже видели пользователя Дух сообщества ♦. Он удаляет вопросы самостоятельно, без вмешательства кого-либо, в следующих ситуациях:
>
> Если вопросу более 30 дней и он...
>   * имеет рейтинг -1 и менее;
>   * не имеет ответов;
>   * не заблокирован
>   … такой вопрос будет удален.

- [**Ссылка 2**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108078/326972)

> С другой стороны, вопрос исчезнет без следа для тех, кто имеет менее 10k репутации. Они будут перенаправлены на страницу 404, в результате чего  пользователи с небольшой репутацией будут понимать, что произошло. Они также не получают любого рода уведомления по данным вопросам.

---

---

### Предложения

1. Понизить рейтинг неотвеченного вопроса, при котором он будет удалён с -1 до -3 (а ещё лучше - -5).
2. Уведомлять участниц и участников, чьи вопросы удалены.

Один мой вопрос с -1 (не оспариваю минус, сейчас бы по-другому тот вопрос задал) был также удалён, вероятнее всего, автоматически. Никаких уведомлений не получал.

---

---

### Аргументы

1. Смотрим [**правило**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/199934):

> Каковы критерии для удаления?
>   Относительно вопросов, удаляются сообщения, которые не добавляют ничего нового на сайт. В основном это касается большинства закрытых вопросов, которые нельзя улучшить и открыть повторно. Но иногда полезно оставить дубликаты вопросов, чтобы облегчить будущим пользователям поиск исходного вопроса.

Полагаю, практика автоматического удаления нарушает данное правило. Сомневаюсь, что все удалённые вопросы «не добавляли ничего нового на сайт».

2. Разве наносят Stack Overflow вопросы с -1 и -2 с какой-либо вред, ущерб? Какова целесообразность их автоматического сноса?
3. На момент написания данного сообщения [**у меня 10 знаков**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b0-%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85?tab=badges) «Возрождение» — 2 или более баллов за ответы на старые вопросы. [**VladD — 15**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd?tab=badges), [**Qwertiy — 16**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy?tab=badges), [**cheops — вообще 51**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205020/cheops?tab=badges). Участники, готовые отвечать не только на свежее, на этом сайте присутствуют. Отвечая на почившие в бозе вопросы с -1 и -2 мы могли бы принести больше пользы сообществу.
4. Если вопросу проставлено пять минусов — да, с высокой долей вероятности, он заслуживает удаления. Один же минус же ещё отнюдь ничего не говорит о безнадёжности вопроса. Нельзя говорить о репрезентативности, основываясь только на одном-единственном голосе. Здесь часто ставят их, не комментируя, о причинах остаётся догадываться. К тому же за минус к вопросу у минусующего не снимается баллов.
5. Ответы, набравшие множество минусов, не удаляются автоматически, хотя ответы минусуют менее охотно, ведь у минусующего ответ снимается балл репутации. Почему же должно удалять вопросы?
6. Уведомления за определённое количество суток до удаления предоставили бы шанс авторам  отредактировать свои вопросы, сделав их лучше, повысив их шансы получить хороший ответ, что выгодно как самим авторам, так и Stack Overflow на русском.
7. «Тихое» удаление не позволяет скопировать код вопроса. Если захочется задать его в другом месте, придётся всё писать заново.
8. Удаление без уведомлений неприятно, у авторов удалённых вопросов может сложиться негативное мнение о сайте.

---

---

### Примеры

Собрал несколько неотвеченных вопросов, имевших на момент, когда их увидел, рейтинг -1 или -2, т. е. в текущей редакции правил в скором времени всех их постигнет незавидная участь. Согласен, что они неидеальны, но настолько ли уж плохи, что подлежат удалению? С таким подходом половину вопросов сайта можно сносить, и я не утрирую.

- [**Обработка команд для сервера**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/578283/199934)
- [**Как обрезать изображение полигонально?**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574394/199934)
- [**Python 3, преобразование JSON-списка в словарь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585982/199934)
- [**C++ QLineEdit не выводится текст**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573596/199934)
- [**Нужно выбирать рандомное число через js, но предотвратить изменение числа через исходный код**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584672/199934)
- [**Аналог ByteArray из ActionScript в JavaScript**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584176/199934)
- [**Как при нажатии на кнопку добавить сообщения в ListView?**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581680/199934)

Comment: «Тихое» удаление не позволяет скопировать код вопроса. Если захочется задать его в другом месте, придётся всё писать заново. - разве авторы удаленных вопросов и ответов не продолжают их видеть?

Comment: Если вы считаете, что вопросы из собранного списка не стоит удалять - просто плюсаните их.

Comment: @PashaPash, я не вижу своих удалённых вопросов. [**Похоже**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108078/326972), нужно иметь 10 тысяч баллов репутации. Спасибо.

Comment: даже по прямой ссылке, например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498856/ ?

Comment: @PashaPash, нет, так видно вопрос, спасибо! Но в [**списке удалённых вопросов**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/199934) он через какое-то время пропал — http://i.imgur.com/yitB7be.png . Как Вы получили прямую ссылку?

Comment: Это список *недавно* удаленных вопросов. В общем списке вопросов до него все еще можно долистать :)

Comment: @PashaPash, я не вижу этого вопроса в [**общем списке**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b0-%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85?tab=questions&sort=votes) — http://i.imgur.com/qiGN5Pw.png . Спасибо.

Comment: @PashaPash, кажется, они там только полгода живут, а может и месяц, а потом исчезают.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, он же модератор - он видит удалённые вопросы в списках.

Comment: @Qwertiy и после этого не могу их развидеть :(